# Define a conditional constant for all builds in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, preprocessor-directive, msbuild-propertygroup

I have a project with some code. I want to determine is RyuJIT is used and if so then write `RyuJIT` otherwise `LegacyJIT`.

I write:

```
#if RuyJIT
            Console.WriteLine("RyuJIT");
#else
            Console.WriteLine("LegacyJIT");
#endif
```

then I'm trying to define a constant. So i open my `.csproj` in notepad and write following:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants Condition=" $(TargetFrameworkVersion.Replace('v', '')) &gt;= 4.6 ">RyuJIT</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But it doesn't work: constant is not defined thus second line is always compiled for any target framework. What am I doing wrong? How can I share this constant between builds?

Comment: Very broad word 'doesn't work' :( :(  Try to add constant when it _not_ RyuJIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `Choose` node. Additionaly, now I'm able to reference `.Net 4.6-only` dlls.

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition=" $(TargetFrameworkVersion.Replace('v', '')) &gt;= 4.6 ">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
        <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.1.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>SIMD</DefineConstants>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```

I replaced `RyuJIT` with `SIMD` because it's more suitable